# How do I search my files for a suffix?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-search

I have been trying to order my computer files, some of which share a common suffix which I'd like to be able to use to group them together. I know that Windows explorer can be used to search a directory for file prefixes (e.g., by typing the prefix into the search bar), but what about suffixes? For example I have a directory containing the skeletal formulae of several drugs and the drugs with the suffix "-azole" I'd like to add a folder I've created in this directory called "Azoles". Is it possible for me to search the directory for all files with the suffix "-azole" so I can then drag them into this new folder?

Comment: Don't wildcards work? (Perhaps I didn't understand your question correctly) e.g. `*000.*` on search bar will display all files end with "000", with any extension. e.g. unins000.dat. If I didn't understand your question correctly, please add some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wildcards work?

e.g. `*000.*` on search bar will display all files end with "000", with any extension. e.g. unins000.dat.

(Written as an answer at request)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
I create a few files to make an example and **put them in the Tests folder**

[image: files]

Then I use the search zone of the explore to search by the suffix -azole.

[image: search result]

As you can see it could find the desired elements (it found them in Tests folder)

If you would click to get into that folder you can then drag the elements to any other folder. The search process would normally dynamically updates itself to display the destination folder among the folders that match your search criteria